# HTML Button who fires a Postgres sql statement in the background?

Tags: html, sql

I have a HTML Button. I wanna click on this Button and in the background it should fire a postgres SQL Statement. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a very basic scenario of web development. You should find some learning resources about this versatile topic. Stack Overflow can not offer that.

Comment: Learn about the HTTP request/response flow, HTML forms with POST requests, a backend programming language and how to handle database connection with it. A broad answer for a broad question, sorry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.